# How do I get rounded corners in twitter bootstrap to have rounded corners in ie8?

Tags: css, internet-explorer, twitter-bootstrap, rounded-corners

I have an application in CodeIgniter and I'm using twitter bootstrap but I can't get rounded corners in ie8.

I've tried CSS3 pie with no success. I tried placing the .htc file in various places (`appname/PIE.htc`) and placing `AddType text/x-component .htc` but with no success either.

So I've now tried using `border-radius.htc` instead. My CSS and (`border-radius.htc`) are located in `appname/application/views/resources/css/`:

My css file looks like:

```
@import url(bootstrap.css);

input[type="file"],
input[type="image"],
input,textarea,
input[type="file"]:focus, 
input[type="radio"]:focus,
input[type="checkbox"]:focus,
select:focus,
.input-prepend input,
.input-append input,
.input-prepend select,
.input-append select,
.input-prepend .uneditable-input,
.input-append .uneditable-input,
.input-prepend .add-on,
.input-append .add-on,
.input-prepend .btn,
.input-append .btn ,
.input-prepend .add-on:first-child,
.input-prepend .btn:first-child,
.input-append .add-on:last-child,
.input-append .btn:last-child,
.input-prepend.input-append .add-on:first-child,
.input-prepend.input-append .btn:first-child,
.input-prepend.input-append .add-on:last-child,
.input-prepend.input-append .btn:last-child,
.control-group.warning input:focus,
.control-group.warning select:focus,
.control-group.warning textarea:focus,
.control-group.error input:focus,
.control-group.error select:focus,
.control-group.error textarea:focus,
.control-group.success input:focus,
.control-group.success select:focus,
.control-group.success textarea:focus,
input:focus:required:invalid:focus,
textarea:focus:required:invalid:focus,
select:focus:required:invalid:focus,
.uneditable-input,
.btn,
.btn.active,
.btn:active,
.btn-group > .dropdown-toggle,
.btn-group.open .dropdown-toggle,
.btn-large,
.btn-group > .btn,
.btn-group > .btn:first-child,
.btn-group > .btn:last-child,
.btn-group > .dropdown-toggle,
.btn-group > .btn.large:first-child,
.btn-group > .btn.large:last-child,
.btn-group > .large.dropdown-toggle,
.navbar-inner,
.navbar-search .search-query,
.navbar-search .search-query:focus,
.navbar-search .search-query.focused,
.navbar .btn-navbar,
.navbar .btn-navbar .icon-bar,
.nav-tabs > li > a,
.nav-pills > li > a,
.nav-tabs.nav-stacked > li > a,
.nav-tabs.nav-stacked > li:first-child > a,
.nav-tabs.nav-stacked > li:last-child > a,
.nav-tabs .dropdown-menu,
.nav-pills .dropdown-menu,
.tabs-below > .nav-tabs > li > a,
.tabs-left > .nav-tabs > li > a,
.tabs-right > .nav-tabs > li > a,
.nav-collapse .dropdown-menu,
.nav-collapse .navbar-form,
.nav-collapse .navbar-search,
.nav-collapse .nav > li > a,
.nav-collapse .dropdown-menu a,
.nav-collapse .btn,
.nav-collapse .dropdown-menu,
.navbar-inner,
.navbar-fixed-top .navbar-inner,
.navbar-fixed-bottom .navbar-inner,
.navbar .btn-navbar .icon-bar,
.subnav,
.subnav .nav > li > a,
.subnav .nav > li:first-child > a,
.subnav .nav > li:first-child > a:hover,
.subnav .nav > .active > a,
.subnav .nav > .active > a:hover,
.search-query,
.breadcrumb,
.pagination ul,
.pagination li:first-child a,
.pagination li:last-child a,
.pager a,
.thumbnail,
a.thumbnail:hover,
.progress,
.progress .bar,
.popover-inner,
.popover-title,
.popover-content,
.modal,
.modal-footer,
.dropdown-menu,
.well,
.well-large,
.well-small,
.alert,
.hero-unit,
.tooltip-inner,
.typeahead,
.accordion-group
{
-moz-border-radius:10px;
-webkit-border-radius:10px;
behavior: url(border-radius.htc);
}
```

This still doesn't work in ie8. Am I doing something wrong?

Comment: try something like this: behavior: url(/assets/js/PIE.htc);

Comment: I don't have a directory called assets and I am no longer using PIE.htc.

Comment: Well, PIE works (generally speaking) in TBS. The directory doesn't have to be 'assets' but the path needs to be absolute with the forward slash ( / ).

Comment: Is your .htc file definitely in the same directory as this css file?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The first thing I'd say is that applying a complex Javascript effect like this to that many CSS selectors is going to have a noticeable performance impact on IE8. If at all possible, I would strongly advise you to reign in your desire for rounded corners on everything.

I won't hurt your IE8 users to have to sacrifice a few eye candy effects, but it might be more painful for them if the site has noticeable poor performance.

But ignoring that point for the time being, let's look at how to get it working.

I would suggest giving CSS3Pie another go -- you mention that you've not had any success with it, but you clearly haven't had any success with the other scripts either. CSS3Pie is a significantly better piece of software than any of the other various rounded corner hacks out there for IE. Yes, Pie has a few quirks, but compared with the others, it's very very easy to get working.

And bear in mind that the rounded-corner.htc program hasn't been updated since 2009, so it doesn't know about IE9 or IE10. Those browsers do support border-radius, but will also load an htc file. I haven't tried it, but that might mean you could get some unwanted effects. On the other hand, CSS3Pie is up-to-date, and knows what to do with various IE versions.

If you're getting no corner effects at all, the most likely problem is the URL of the htc file. You say you've tried a few combinations, but have you checked the IE dev tools to see what file it is actually accessing? Press F12 to bring it up, and then refresh your page. You should see all the files being downloaded. Look for the htc file, and see what URL IE is trying to download. If it's getting a 404, then you've found your problem. I suspect that this is the issue, but obviously I can't tell without seeing your site.

Another possibility is that you've got ActiveX switched off in your browser. Both CSS3Pie and rounded-corner.htc use IE's VML language to create their effects. But this is an activeX control, so users with activeX disabled will not see the rounded corners.

If all else fails with the HTC option, you could try CSS3Pie's plain Javascript option. This allows you to run the same code, but as a regular Javascript in the page. It's not quite as neat as the HTC option, but it does help in some cases where HTC just isn't possible.

Hope that helps.